# Getting an invocation error while unit testing the method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I have the handler method below where I am testing for invalid name exception.

```
....
namespace SchemaModeler.Host.Modules;
........
public class CreateWorkspaceHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateWorkspaceInput, Workspace?>
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext> _dbContextFactory;
    private readonly ITopicEventSender _eventSender;

    public async ValueTask<Workspace?> Handle(
        CreateWorkspaceInput request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await using AppDbContext dbContext =
            await _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Name))
        {
            throw new InvalidNameException(request.Name);
        }

        Organization organization =
            await dbContext.Organizations
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == request.OrganizationId, cancellationToken)
            ?? throw new EntityNotFoundException(request.OrganizationId, nameof(Organization)); 
       .................
        var workspace = new Workspace
        {
           .......
            Organization = organization,
           ........
        };

       .......
        await _eventSender.SendAsync(nameof(WorkspaceSubscriptions.OnCreatedWorkspace), workspace,
            cancellationToken);
        return workspace;
    }
}
```

And below is the test method for the same

```
....
namespace SchemaModeler.Host.Tests.UnitTests;
....
[UsesVerify]
[Collection("Postgres")]
public class WorkspaceTests : TestBase
{
    public override async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await base.InitializeAsync();  // Call the base InitializeAsync() method
        await using AppDbContext context = CreateDbContext();
        context.Workspaces.Add(WorkspaceMockFixture.Workspaces);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    [Fact]
    public async Task Handle_InvalidName_ThrowsInvalidNameException()
    {
        var organizationId = new Guid();
       .........
        var mockOrganizationsDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Organization>>();
        mockOrganizationsDbSet.Setup(m => m.FindAsync(It.IsAny<object[]>()))
                              .ReturnsAsync((Organization)null);
        MockDbContext.Setup(dbContext => dbContext.Set<Organization>())
                     .Returns(mockOrganizationsDbSet.Object);
        ..........    
        MockDbContext.Verify(
            dbContext => dbContext.Set<Organization>().FindAsync(
                It.IsAny<object[]>(),
                CancellationToken
            ),
            Times.Once
        );  // getting error here 
        ..........
    }
}
```

I am getting the below exception.

> Moq.MockException :  Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0
> times: dbContext => dbContext.Set< Organization >().FindAsync(It.IsAny<object[]>(),
> CancellationToken)
>
> Performed invocations:
>
> MockAppDbContext:1 (dbContext):    No invocations performed.

Can anyone suggest any idea on how to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell, but at least of of the problems is that `mockOrganizationsDbSet.Setup(m => m.FindAsync(It.IsAny<object[]>()))` sets up a method which does not accept `CancellationToken` but you verifying one that accepts such parameter. Try:

```cs
MockDbContext.Verify(
    dbContext => dbContext.Set<Organization>().FindAsync(
        It.IsAny<object[]>(),
        CancellationToken
    ),
    Times.Once
);
```

Also maybe you will need to split the verification in two (`MockDbContext.Verify` and `mockOrganizationsDbSet.Verify`).

P.S.

Personally I'm not a big fun of mocking `DbContext`, usually you don't care what exactly is used on the context, but that it returns needed data and for that I either use test containers or [SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#sqlite-in-memory).